# Templates in web.py

Tags: python, forms, templates, web, web.py

I try to render a template with web.py and some seconds after another, I'm not too much into Python so I could need a little help :).

What I try to achive (return can be returned only once for sure, but I guess you'll get it what I mean)

```
class index: 
    def GET(self):
        return render.formone('')
        time.sleep(30)
        return render.formtwo('')
```

So I need to get around that return somehow, but I have no idea how...

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to render two forms at the same time? You simply cannot send two responses this way. Your script will end after first return.

If I understand you correctly, you want to serve two forms at the same time (meaning you want to join them)? If yes, then look at this [example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/concatenate_two_rendered_templates).
Basically you first render both forms

```
formone = render.formone('') 
formtwo = render.formtwo('')
```

And then join them and send the response

```
return render.index(unicode(formone), unicode(formtwo))
```

If you don't want to serve them at the same time, this can't be done this way. You may do this via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (ie event from webpage, send request and ask for second form after clicking on some element or whatever) or sending another standard non-async request (submitting first form).

Comment: I know I can't have two responses, anyway i want them with a little delay between (and variable change) so guess i have to try the ajax way, do you know any good sources or even similar code?

Comment: You can check examples regarding ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You won't have to do anything specific with your python server, just set up different url (or catch an argument) and then reply with your second form. AJAX (jquery) will connect to your server, fetch second form and then you can replace the first one with new form

Comment: i solved my problem with a bit different approach, i now only have to render one... but thanks for your help, i will keep it for future use